# ellipsis "when he was young" vs "when young"

Tags: ellipsis

I have made up the sentences below.

(1a) Jack was good-looking when he was young.

(1b) Jack was good-looking when young.

Is (1b) correct? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> (1a) *Jack was good-looking when he was young.*
>
> (1b) *Jack was good-looking when young.*

Yes, (1b) is fine. It's an example of ellipsis of the subject pronoun "he" and the auxiliary verb "was".

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.